# How to show the ActiveX Yellow bar?

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, activex, ocx

I'm trying to **set up a webpage that downloads the OCX** and installs it with the user permission when the user **right click in the yellow bar**

Note: *it's a business app and I know... IE, but 95% of company customers use it and it's easy for us to move from Windows > OCX first and then to full WebService*

What I did was create a cab file with:

```
- eds.cab (signed with an SSL certificate)
     |--- EDS.ocx
     |--- setup.inf
```

the **setup.inf** has this code:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"

[Add.Code]
EDS.ocx=EDS.ocx

[EDS.ocx]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={8EC68701-329D-4567-BCB5-9EE4BA43D358}
FileVersion=3,5,0,150
RegisterServer=yes
```

and then the **webpage contains the**  tag like this:

```
<object 
    id="ActiveX" 
    classid="CLSID:8EC68701-329D-4567-BCB5-9EE4BA43D358" 
    width="14" 
    height="14" 
    codebase="http://localhost/EDS.Webservice/EDS.cab#version=3,5,0,150">
    <param name="tabName" value="Stop:http://localhost/EDS.Webservice/" />
</object>
```

and they I navigate to the http://localhost/EDS.Webservice/

The issue is that I do not get that yellow bar, just the ACL asking me to accept it.

> **Does anyone know what I could have been missing?**

It only shows the ACL message on Windows 7, never the yellow bar first like, Flash plugin... :-(

---

**added**

What we are after:

[image]

Thank you.

---

**Added**

**Internet Explorer** Settings are as **Default**, both Security on Advanced Tab as well Trust Domains

Comment: Have you actually tried it on an internet address? Even 127.0.0.1 will do as it could be a zone issue, sometimes the different zones will give you a different display for installing an unknown control.

And I assume you are signing with a code-signing certificate, not one designed for SSL? :)

Comment: yes I did... even hosted in our server in the company and access that page at home (no VPN access or direct connection to company). :(

Comment: and yes, the certificate was created using the code signing tool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you serving your page from? If it's from localhost/inside the local network, it will have a different security policy applied - even with all settings as default. Try publishing it to an external server and see what happens (or failing that, change the settings for "trusted" site to be the same as "internet")

You should also check what's happening with regards to signing of the component - does your object have a certificate that's trusted by your domain/pc setup?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in absent **Deployment** section. Try to modify your .inf file:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
EDS.ocx=EDS.ocx

[Deployment] 
InstallScope=user|machine

[EDS.ocx]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={8EC68701-329D-4567-BCB5-9EE4BA43D358}
FileVersion=3,5,0,150
RegisterServer=yes
```

Comment: we have been comparing our own `.inf` with several websites (as we can get the `.cab` file and check the `.inf` that's inside the cab, and none have that option, though, all show the yellow bar :-(

Comment: I have tested my own CAB and the yellow bar wasn’t shown without Deployment section.  Another guess is to ensure that control is unregistered before CAB installation (regsvr32 EDS.ocx –u). Also you can try to add AdvancedINF tag into version section. I’ll add it to my post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nail IE settings and then talk to domain admin(s) to push it as a policy. Yellow bar is for apps that are considered untrusted and you want your app to be considered fully trusted on client boxes - you just want IE settings tweaked to that it shows yellow bar for all apps - even those totally signed and trusted and coming from local/corp net.

Comment: I want to show the yellow bar with the defaults on, as we have tested. The plugin is signed normally like Flash is, but instead of the Yellow bar saying that "This page uses a plugin..." we only get the "Accept" message box from the ACL. :( it is much more "common" to have the yellow bar for such and that's what we are trying to accomplish. ... with no luck I might add.

Comment: Flash is not coming in from a trusted zone.

Comment: in our tests outside our own domain, we have the same... we did not add the domain to the trust zone, so it should behave the same as Flash, don't you agree?